# How to configure thread count on Spark Driver node?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka, apache-spark-standalone

We are running spark streaming job in stand-alone cluster mode with deploy mode as the client. This streaming job polls messages from kafka topic periodically, and the logs generated at the driver node is flushed to a `txt` file.

After running continuosly for 2 -3 days, the job is getting crashed with `Too many open files` error. Upon investigating we found that the spark is creating too many threads at driver node and each thread is opening a file descriptor to flush the logs into `txt` file, which is causing to breach `fd` threshold set by the operating system. At one point, we could see ~ 1500 threads are spawned.

I was wondering is there any way/configuration that we can set to limit the thread count that the spark framework is creating on the driver node?

We are using spark version `2.3.1`

Comment: Streaming or structured streaming?

Comment: It is streaming